# Organization chart not working in Chrome

Tags: 2013, mysite, silverlight, chrome

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise environment. We are using the organization chart which users find very fancy. The problem is that it only shows the HTML version in Google Chrome, not the `Silverlight` one.

It works well in IE and other browsers. Is it somehow possible to make it work with `Silverlight` in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue and we learn that google is opting out from silverlight and they are disabled the silverlight plugin support in chrome.

Their is still a workaround which you can use till end of 2015.to enable the silverlight in chrome follow these instructions:

1. install the Silverlight component on PC.
2. Enter `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` into your Chrome address bar.
3. find **NPAPI Mac, Windows** on the page(1st one) and Click **Enable.**
4. at the end of page click **Relaunch Now** to activate the changes.

After this you may see the permission error.

1. Click on the puzzle piece at the far right of the address bar.
2. Select Always allow plug-ins on content.testout.com and click Done.

Alternate is, you can use IE or Firefox for permanent Solution.
[KBA-098 - Silverlight Plugin Blocked in Chrome Browser](http://www.testout.com/home/support/knowledge-base/kba-098---silverlight-plugin-blocked-in-chrome-browser)